# ¿Por que me sale como no realizada la peticion PUT con POSTMAN?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, postman

Antes de embarcarme en las rutas de mi aplicacion, he creado realizado algunas peticiones con POSTMAN de las cuales PUT no se me realizan con totalidad.

Esta es mi configuracion de mi servidor en ExpressJS:

```
const express = require('express');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const helmet = require('helmet');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const app = express();

// Settings
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/mevn-curso', { 
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
    useCreateIndex: true
})
        .then(db => console.log('DB is connected'))
        .catch(err => console.log(err));

mongoose.set('useNewUrlParser', true);
mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);
mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);

// Middlewares
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(helmet());

// Routes
app.use('/tasks/', require('./routes/tasks'));


// Static files
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))

app.listen(app.get('port'), ()=> {
    console.log('Server on port', app.get('port'));
});
```

me funciona normalmente y esta es la ruta que estoy utilizando, que esta dentro del archivo tasks.js en la carpeta de rutas:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const Task = require('../models/Task');


router.get('/', async (req,res)=> {
  const tasks = await Task.find();
  res.json(tasks);
})

router.post('/', async (req,res) => {
   const task = new Task(req.body);
   await task.save();
   res.json({
       status: "Task Saved"
   })
})

router.put('/:id', async (req,res)=> {
    console.log(req.params._id);
    console.log(req.body);
    await Task.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params._id, req.body)
    res.json('recivied');
    console.log('Listo')
})

module.exports = router;
```

En consola no parece darme ningun error. Yo hago la peticion con POSTMAN normal, y me devuelve los logs de la consola. Incluso el servidor me responde el json y todo. Pero lo datos en la base de datos no se cambian.
Esto no pasa con GET o POST, al contrario, todo va viento en popa.

Aca os dejo como hago la peticion con POSTMAN. Primero que todo les voy a mostrar los datos que ya tengo en la base de datos, con la peticion get que se hace normalmente con el navegador:

[image: Peticion get con el navegador]

listo, a la hora de hacer la peticion PUT esta es mi configuracion en POSTMAN:

[image: Configuracion json]

como ven, es un content type de tipo json porque eso es lo que voy a procesar, luego viene el body:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y pues cuando hago la peticion PUT esto me sale en consola:

[image: Lo que me sale en consola]

Todo parece estar totalmente normal. Sin embargo los datos siguen siendo los mismos cuando hago la peticion get. Estos no se actualizan.

¿Que creen pueda ser? El tutorial que estoy siguiendo es este: https://youtu.be/ARIzrNwA5HQ?t=3287 lo he colocado desde el momento en que toca la ruta put.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

en tu consola al momento de imprimir el ID aparece undefined. Es por eso que no se actualiza ningún registro, no le pasas un ID válido, para capturar el ID de la url basta con que pongas req.params.id

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ha funcionado. Pense que la palabra que definia el id era la que me salia en el json que se generaba.